# How to refer globally to a object created in a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter

I'm trying to program a GUI in `tkinter` that sets the root to a "darkmode" waits a specific amount of time and then closing or withdrawing itself and at the same moment a new Toplevel should be generated. The withdrawed main window should pop up again after I closed the Toplevel. Therefore I used the if statement, but I get a `NameError: newWindow not defined`, evenhough I set it to global.

This my code:

```
from tkinter import *

def answer(event):
    AnsLabel["text"]="You clicked the Button!"

def darkmode(event):
    Hallo["fg"]="white"
    Hallo["bg"]="black"
    main["bg"]="black"
    AnsLabel["bg"]="black"
    AnsLabel["fg"]="white"
    button["bg"]="black"
    button["fg"]="white"
    main.after(3000,createWindow)

def createWindow():
    global newWindow
    newWindow=Toplevel()
    newLabel=Label(newWindow,text="You found the secret function!")
    newLabel.pack()
    main.withdraw()

main=Tk()
Hallo=Label(main,text="Hello")
button=Button(main,text="BUTTON")
button.bind("<Button-1>",answer)
button.bind("<Button-3>",darkmode)
AnsLabel=Label(main,text="Hello!")
Hallo.pack()
button.pack()
AnsLabel.pack()
if not newWindow.winfo_exists():
    main.deiconify()
main.mainloop()
```

Comment: `newWindow` isn't created until `createWindow` is called for the first time. The `global` statement doesn't define a variable; it just informs the code generator that the assignment to `newWindow` should create/modify a global instead of a local if and when the name is assigned to.

Comment: @chepner but isn't the instance newWindow initiated when I use the = operator and a class as an operant on the other side as I have done it one line below?

Comment: Only once `createWindow` is *called*, which won't appear to happen for the first time until the main loop is started. You try to access `newWindow` *before* that.

Comment: In fact, `createWindow()` isn't called until the user clicks Button 3, which might never happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go. The issue with your code is that it runs the if statement then the Tkinter mainloop. in order to get your code to work you need to bind a function.

```
from tkinter import *

def answer(event):
    AnsLabel["text"]="You clicked the Button!"

def darkmode(event):
    Hallo["fg"]="white"
    Hallo["bg"]="black"
    main["bg"]="black"
    AnsLabel["bg"]="black"
    AnsLabel["fg"]="white"
    button["bg"]="black"
    button["fg"]="white"
    main.after(3000,createWindow)

def createWindow():
    global newWindow
    newWindow=Toplevel()
    newLabel=Label(newWindow,text="You found the secret function!")
    newLabel.pack()
    main.withdraw()
    newWindow.bind(sequence="<Destroy>", func=lambda x: main.deiconify())
    

main=Tk()
Hallo=Label(main,text="Hello")
button=Button(main,text="BUTTON")
button.bind("<Button-1>",answer)
button.bind("<Button-3>",darkmode)
AnsLabel=Label(main,text="Hello!")
Hallo.pack()
button.pack()
AnsLabel.pack()



main.mainloop()
```

The code I changed is here.

```
def createWindow():
    global newWindow
    newWindow=Toplevel()
    newLabel=Label(newWindow,text="You found the secret function!")
    newLabel.pack()
    main.withdraw()
    newWindow.bind(sequence="<Destroy>", func=lambda x: main.deiconify())
```

its easier and cleaner to use classes

```
from tkinter import *

class App(Tk):

    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()

        self.hallo=Label(self,text="Hello")
        self.button=Button(self,text="BUTTON")
        self.button.bind("<Button-1>",self.answer)
        self.button.bind("<Button-3>",self.darkmode)
        self.ansLabel=Label(self,text="Hello!")
        self.hallo.pack()
        self.button.pack()
        self.ansLabel.pack()

    def answer(self, event):
        self.ansLabel["text"]="You clicked the Button!"

    def darkmode(self, event) -> None:

        self.hallo["fg"]="white"
        self.hallo["bg"]="black"
        self["bg"]="black"
        self.ansLabel["bg"]="black"
        self.ansLabel["fg"]="white"
        self.button["bg"]="black"
        self.button["fg"]="white"
        self.after(3000,self.createWindow)

    def createWindow(self):
        global newWindow
        newWindow=Toplevel()
        newLabel=Label(newWindow,text="You found the secret function!")
        newLabel.pack()
        self.withdraw()
        newWindow.bind(sequence="<Destroy>", func=self.reopen)

    def reopen(self, event):

        self.deiconify()
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

> Only once createWindow is called, which won't appear to happen for the first time until the main loop is started. You try to access newWindow before that. –
> chepner

I found a solution by adding the Variable `Dark` to check if `createWindow` was called before. Never the less it is not working as expected, because the `main.deiconify()` don't open the `main` window again.

```
def answer(event):
    AnsLabel["text"]="You clicked the Button!"
def darkmode(event):
    Hallo["fg"]="white"
    Hallo["bg"]="black"
    main["bg"]="black"
    AnsLabel["bg"]="black"
    AnsLabel["fg"]="white"
    button["bg"]="black"
    button["fg"]="white"
    global Dark
    Dark=True
    main.after(3000,createWindow)
def createWindow():
    global newWindow
    newWindow=Toplevel()
    newLabel=Label(newWindow,text="You found the secret function!")
    newLabel.pack()
    main.withdraw()
Dark=False
main=Tk()
Hallo=Label(main,text="Hello")
button=Button(main,text="BUTTON")
button.bind("<Button-1>",answer)
button.bind("<Button-3>",darkmode)
AnsLabel=Label(main,text="Hello!")
Hallo.pack()
button.pack()
AnsLabel.pack()
if Dark and not newWindow.winfo_exists():
    main.deiconify()
main.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

In line 25, add `darkmode` method to keyword `command=` in `Button` widget.

In line 33, Change this:

```
if not newWindow.winfo_exists():
```

to:

```
if not main.winfo_exists():
```

Screenshot:

[image]